# Ubuntu 22.04 stopped recognizing USB device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, tablet, drawing

Recently my drawing tablet stopped being
recognized by the system. When I first plugged it in, everything was OK and it worked, but now it is not, and I cant find the issue. `lsusb` shows nothing:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3491 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:57de Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`dmesg` and syslog tailing don't react when I unplug/plug the device, but it is powered when I plug it in(there is a blue indicator on the tablet). Plugged USB stick in the same port, and it works. I also tried installing OpenTabletDriver and DIGImend drivers but to no avail. I am sure there is a problem specifically with drivers and kernel, not with the device. How can I restore the drivers? Thank you. *Tablet name is Parblo Ninos M, just in case, laptop is ASUS X756UQ*

UPD: Tried it on another Ubuntu device, it works flawlessly

Comment: Things may have changed a lot since I got mine, but it would only ever be recognised if it was connected before boot.

Comment: unfortunately, it did't help me. situation is the same even after power off and replugging

Comment: @StasStas Did you install an earlier kernel and/or tested the device on a different computer to confirm your suspicion?

Comment: Yes, I tested it on another device, works great